# Need to set up an event listener in django

Tags: django, events, signals, django-channels

I need to listen to an external API from another application.Both applications have same number of users.so change in any app will need to be update on another app. SO planning to setup an event listener to communicate b/w applications.

Appreciate any help to setup this in DJango.

Comment: You can set up a webhook in Django and call this webhook from the second app whenever that event happens.

Comment: Can you share an example , how to setup a webhook.

Comment: A webhook is simply a URL that you define in your app. E.g. you need to write a view in Django and then give it a URL. The View handles the logic using the payload that was received on the URL endpoint. You can probably google how to set up a webhook.